# Media query inspector only availbleon chrome?

Tags: web, frontend, media-queries, devtools, visual-web-developer

I am trying to find this feature on Firefox or even polypane but can't seem to be able to find it
[chrome media query toggle in Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVpTt.png)

I have tried to find another browser that offers this functionality but apparently it's only on Chrome and Edge ?